# Libreoffice Calc template for CSV Imports

Tags: templates, csv, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I have made a function in Scilab that saves data in a *.csv file, and opens it with Libreoffice-calc.

I also made a template in Calc, that sets textsize and alternating row colors.

Is there a command line argument to select a template that the csv file gets imported to?

//John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use [csv2odf](http://csv2odf.sourceforge.net), it can insert csv data into a LibreOffice spreadsheet template.